# how do you use dmax to find the second highest value in a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have a list of gender in one column and numeric values in another column, I want to find the highest value of f (female) the second highest and the third highest, and I want the highest, second and third highest of m (male).  I have used dmax to find the highest and if I put "<" and the result of the highest value from the dmax formula in the criteria, I get a zero.  If the high was 151, and if put <151 (the actual value) in the criteria it finds the second and third highest.
What can be done?

Comment: How do you want to handle ties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - top 3 highest changes when you change the gender value to f or m in cell E2:

Formula for:

E3: `=E2`

E4: `=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,E2)`

E5: `=DMAX(A1:B9,2,D1:E2)`

E6: `=DMAX(A1:B9,2,E1:F2)`

D2: `="<"&E4`

F2: `="<"&E5`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this as an array formula for the first,

```
=large(if(a$2:a$99="f", b$2:b$99), row(1:1))
```

Fill down for the second, third, etc. Change *f* to *m* for males.

Answer (score 1):

*Since DMAX will not work properly,* therefore I would like to suggest that you can use this **CSE Formula** in a blank Cell, to find the Second Higest for Females.

{=(INDEX(B2:B10,MATCH(LARGE(IF(A$2:A$10 = "Female",B2:B10),**2**),B2:B10,0)))}

**NB:** *For 3rd Highest you need to Replace 2 with 3.*

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend to not use dmax. put this formula in column c.

=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,A:A,">"&A2)+1

[image]